# Regex match multiple initial tokens with common following token

Tags: regex

Given a string like:

```
ASSUME @pete, @grey and @matt_c ARE really tall
```

is there a way I can use regex to extract:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `@pete`
2.  `really tall`
MATCH 2
1.  `@grey`
2.  `really tall`
MATCH 3
1.  `@matt_c`
2.  `really tall`
```

Further, is there a way I can do it with the @ being optional for each of them?

**Constraints:** The syntax must be of the form ASSUME [names] ARE [statement] where:

- [names] consists of one or more [name]s separated by `,` `(space)`, `&` or `and`
- [name] consists of alphanumeric + underscores or dashes

Happy to answer any questions relating to setup. A starting point with the example strings I'm trying to make work can be found here: http://regex101.com/r/fS9oK5/4

Comment: This was based on a friend's implementation - trying to handle spaces, ampersands, commas and 'and'. Realised my scope is slightly narrower, will update the question.

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly what I was after - but I really wanted to match each name with the end section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a [**Positive Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to capture the overlapping matches.

```
(?=(@[\w-]+).*ARE\s*(.+))
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zI0fR8/4)

Comment: This looks pretty much exactly what I was after (added quick change to match dashes)! Cheers for the edu-link as well, bit of reading for me there...

Comment: On further inspection, This doesn't explicitly match on the ASSUME right? so the lines could start with anything?

Comment: If you need to be sure it starts with ASSUME, use `(?:\G[^@]*|^ASSUME)(@[\w-]+)(?=.*ARE\s*(.+))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
ASSUME (@\w+(?:(?:,?\s@\w+)*\s*and\s*@\w+)?)\sARE\s(.+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fS9oK5/3)

Comment: Really close, but I was looking to get each name individually with the end section. Also I forgot the mention dashes and underscores were acceptable in the names, though it doesn't change your approach much I don't think. This is roughly where I have currently got to as well :(

Comment: please update your demo link with some more lines which reflect the above behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

a little variation from the accepted answer:
you would actually consume the first sub-pattern

```
(@[\w-]+)(?=.*ARE\s(.+))
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/40)

to explicitly match `ASSUME`, depending on your engine and `\G` option

```
(?:^ASSUME\s*|\G[^@]*)(@[\w-]+)(?=.*ARE\s(.+))
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/42)

Comment: This doesn't explicitly match on the ASSUME though right? so the lines could start with anything?

Comment: added matching `ASSUME`